# PostgreSQL insert into table with one value from another table and other values

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables. One table is a correspondance between a technical id (id_tech) and a functional id (fonc_id). The second table contains data.
I would like when I insert values into my second table to be able to automatically add the corresponding id_tech.

I tried these two queries but it is not working:

```
CREATE TABLE syncro.table1 (id_tech serial, id_fonc character);
INSERT INTO syncro.table1 (id_tech, id_fonc) VALUES (1, 'a');
CREATE TABLE syncro.table2 (id_tech serial, id_fonc character, value1 character);

-- test 1 
INSERT INTO syncro.table2(id_tech, id_fonc, value1)
VALUES (SELECT id_tech FROM syncro.table1 WHERE id_fonc='a', 'a', 't');

-- test 2
WITH id_from_table1 AS (
    SELECT id_tech FROM syncro.table1 WHERE id_fonc='a'
)
INSERT INTO syncro.table2(id_tech, id_fonc, value1)
VALUES (id_from_table1, 'a', 't');
```

Comment: Instead of duplicating the data, you should *not* store the corresponding `id_tech` in `table2` at all. You should `JOIN` it whenever you are doing a query.

Comment: Your first `INSERT` query is the way to go, you just misplaced the closing `)` of the subquery

Comment: Unfortunately I have no say in how the tables were created. Thank you for the parenthesis, I had no idea I had to put them around values and also around the query, it works fine now.